# Calendar event repeating every month but on a certain day

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to create a calendar event repeating every month but on a certain day?

For example our window cleaner started on a Friday and comes every month but on the Friday. Calendar obviously works it out to be a Sunday but it would have been the Friday 2 days prior to that.

Is it possible to do such a thing in Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Select the event. Go into repeat. Select Custom. Change your frequency to monthly and "on the" to whichever day you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you choose a monthly repeat and then choose "on the" you can choose the first Friday of the month for instance.

Is that what you needed?